# Docker-Compose Restart Policy

Tags: docker

I looked thru the docs for docker-compose and I see that Version 3 has a deploy restart policy but it's only for swarm. I tried setting restart_policy on my service but got this error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.web: 'restart_policy'
```

**Is there any way to set a restart policy on services created using docker-compose outside of a swarm?**

Comment: Do you need a version 3 compose file? The purpose of converting to version 3 is for swarm support.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Version 2 supports restart policies, using the `restart` keyword, and should work fine for you if you don't need Swarm (which you said you don't need/want).

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: apache
    restart: always
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart

Compose format version 3 has a parameter called `restart_policy`, but so far as I can tell from documentation it is only valid as part of `deploy`, which is only used when deploying to a Swarm. So version 3 is probably not useful in your case.

Comment: Question was about version 3, try updating the answer? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/restartpolicy

Comment: I think the error in the question was because a non version 3 compose file was used

Comment: @cricket_007 AFAICT from docs, `restart_policy` is only valid inside `deploy`, which is only even used when doing Swarm. Since OP asked about _not_ using Swarm, I feel my original answer should just stay as-is.

Comment: Version 3 says it is recommended for all new compose files. `restart` was simply renamed, AFAICT

Comment: @cricket_007 `restart_policy` is a sub-option of `deploy`, and `deploy` in docs says "This only takes effect when deploying to a swarm with `docker stack deploy`, and is ignored by `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run`."

Comment: does the restart mean when you launch docker via docker-compose up?? it thought doing that always restarts the daemons

Comment: Now version 3 also supports `restart`: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#restart

Answer (score 165):

It looks like a gap in the documentation

In 3rd version, we can still use "restart" inside services same as before in v.2 (except for deploy into swarm)

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-service:
    restart: on-failure:5
```

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart_policy

Comment: i don't see the `:5` as a documented part of the API.  did i miss it?  can you clarify the intent of that?

Comment: It seems they [fixed that gap](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) in the documentation. The :5 is still not documented, and apparently is the "maximum retry count". I used it like that: `restart: unless-stopped:5` and got _maximum retry count cannot be used with restart policy 'unless-stopped'_. I put a 0 instead of 5 and it worked

Comment: Sorry for this silly question but I didn't get what you meant by "except for deploy into swarm". Would  `restart: on-failure:5` work outside of swarm i.e. what I do `docker-compose up` in version `3`?

Comment: The maximum retry count, while undocumented, can be found in the source code [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/f85950ebecfa21b3760756be93867c17a8770d43/compose/config/types.py#L85).

Comment: @riverhorse it appears the gap in the documentation was unfixed.

Comment: @Magnetron yeah, it seems they did unfix it.

Answer (score 11):

Even if you're **NOT** in swarm mode, there is an option called **[--compatibility](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/overview/)** which will work with **restart_policy**, this will attempt to restart even if you're not deploying. The only glitch, is the sub-keys of *'delay'* and *'window'* will be ignored. Here is an example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  container_name: example
  deploy:
    restart_policy:
      condition: on-failure
      max-attempts: 3
```

run this command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml --compatibility up
```

Comment: From the documentation:

    Do not use this in production!

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/#compatibility-mode