# How to restore containers listed in docker ps?

Tags: docker

Since a couple of days `docker ps` displays nothing anymore. I might be the source due to my attempts gaining space using `docker system prune -a`

I'm able to restart all services via `docker restart $(docker ps -a -q)` though
only for the current boot. After reboot I have to repeat the manual restart.

Can't see any entries searching for fail|warn|error using `journalctl -b | grep docker`

Offtopic: Despite being able to restart as explained above,  I can't use the services properly anymore e.g. hassio homeassistant webui

Answer (score 0):

[You might have to use a process manager](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-process-manager) like systemd to specify containers to start when you boot your machine. Docker Compose might help you start a group of services you need. Depending on your process manager, you can add a service entry so it will start your services when booting up. [This article](https://dev.to/suntong/autostart-docker-container-with-systemd-5aod) and [this article](https://blog.container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd) have a few good examples of how to do this with systemd.

You could also add a restart policy, though this applies to running containers and won't persist when you reboot. You can do this [in the docker command](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy): `docker run --restart=always` or in a `docker-compose.yml` file [suggested in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42216597/4676641):

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: apache
    restart: always
```