# how to tell docker-compose to automatically restart failed containers

Tags: docker-compose

is there a way to specify in `docker-compose.yml` that certain container should automatically be resurrected if it dies ? (e.g. if some internal issue killed container, docker-compose will `up` it again)

If this is not possible for individual containers how about global option for all containers (e.g. `docker-compose up --restart-automaticly-or-something` )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216017/docker-compose-restart-policy

Comment: Docker-compose docs are really good: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3#restart_policy

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    image: whatever:latest
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
```